# translating Matlab's bitget() extreme value to python

Tags: python, matlab, binary

I got hold of Matlab code containing such a loop:

```
for n = 1:2^10,
bitget(n-1,10)*2^4;
end;
```

The problem I have is that Matlab (Octave) apparently adds padding bits to the right as such:

```
octave:15> bitget(5,1:10)
ans =

   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

and therefore:

```
octave:14> bitget(5,10)
ans = 0
```

while python does not add those bits, and therefore yields an error.

For this particular situation, am I right in believing that the above Matlab line `bitget(n-1,10)*2^4;` can be translated to python as `(lambda x: 1 if x == 2**9 else 0)(n)*2**4`, since Matlab `bitget(5,10)` would in my opinion only yield 1 if the binary representation of n spans 10 bits, i.e. 2^9 in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misinterpreting the output of Octave. Let's try your example with a different value so we can see what's going on.

```
>> dec2bin(13)
ans = 1101

>> bitget(13,1:10)
ans =

  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

As you can see, the order of the bits has been reversed. In `bitget`, bit `1` is the least significant bit, or `2**0` and bit `10` is `2**9`. It's not padding on the right, it's just reading `0` bits from a numerical type that's larger than the 4 bits required to store the value `13`.

Now, `bitget` will return `1` whenever the specified bit is `1`, regardless of the state of the other bits. So `bitget(n-1,10)` will return `1` not only for `2**9 = 512`, but also for any other value with that bit set; in this case, any value in the range `512..1023`. The equality comparison in your Python function won't give you that so you'll need to change it to a bitwise AND:

```
(lambda x: 1 if x & 2**9 else 0)(n)*2**4
```

Here I've changed `==` to `&` and `2**10` becomes `2**9` to match the value of the 10th bit.